# Haskell on Windows - Stack fails to fetch package index

Tags: windows, haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to install Haskell on Windows. Downloaded the installer and just clicked through everything, then tried to use Stack to install a package, ran it from a temporary folder in which everything has write access:

```
C:\t>stack install hfmt
Using latest snapshot resolver: lts-8.3
Writing implicit global project config file to: C:\sr\global-project\stack.yaml
Note: You can change the snapshot via the resolver field there.
Downloaded lts-8.3 build plan.
Fetching package index ...=.git""=="gui" was unexpected at this time.
C:\sr\indices\Hackage\git-update\all-cabal-hashes>@if ""--git-dir=.git""=="gui" @goto gui
Process exited with ExitFailure 255: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.CMD --git-dir=.git fetch --tags
Failed to fetch package index, retrying.
removeDirectoryRecursive: permission denied (Access is denied.)
```

What's going wrong, and how can I fix it? Or should I forget about Stack and just use Cabal instead?

Tried rerunning the command as administrator. This time the response was instant:

```
C:\t>stack install hfmt
Fetching package index ...=.git""=="gui" was unexpected at this time.
C:\sr\indices\Hackage\git-update\all-cabal-hashes>@if ""--git-dir=.git""=="gui" @goto gui
Process exited with ExitFailure 255: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.CMD --git-dir=.git fetch --tags
Failed to fetch package index, retrying.
removeDirectoryRecursive: permission denied (Access is denied.)
```

Comment: Did you try to run cmd as Administrator? Even if you have write access to the folder, it might try to install some temporary files inside a system folder.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I didn't try to run as administrator. Are you sure it wouldn't have the result of letting it break something (modify a program folder in some weird way)?

Comment: I honestly have no idea, I mean it shouldn't break your system, as I'm pretty sure Stack isn't malicious :) But I can't guarantee anything...

Comment: @Rakete1111 Fair enough :) Tried that just now, posted result.

Comment: I have temporarily deleted my answer (which pointed at [Stack issue #2426](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2426) -- you may still want to have a look at that, as it might be relevant) because the nature of the "was unexpected at this time" error is not clear to me. It makes it look like something is feeding a batch script a bad path (`"--git-dir=.git"`). Have you changed any configuration settings during or after instaling the Platform?

Comment: @duplode No, I didn't touch any settings. I even skipped step 3 as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555250/installing-haskell-on-windows-cabal-config

Comment: The failure is due to `git`, the "removeDirectoryRecursive: permission denied (Access is denied.)" error is a red herring - the task has already failed before that, the most likely situation is that stack simply trudges along and then fails to delete a directory which should have been created by git. As far as I remember, stack will happily use its own version of git if it does not find it on your machine, so try removing your installation of `git` from the path. Regardless, you should run `stack update -v` (as I said in the other question....) to actually see what is happening.