# How to modify cabal config file on windows

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I am installing Haskell on my desktop, which is windows system. I follow the instruction. It says: Modify your cabal config file (you can verify the location by running "cabal user-config init") to contain the following lines:

```
extra-prog-path: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.2\msys\usr\bin
extra-lib-dirs: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.2\mingw\lib
extra-include-dirs: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.2\mingw\include
```

I tried to call "cabal user-config init" in command prompt, but it doesn't work. Anyone know where should I call "cabal user-config init"?

Comment: Thanks guys. I solved it. Seems it is the firewall problem. I closed the firewall and reinstalled again, then it works.

Comment: Related Q: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42555250/2157640