# Step by step installing Haskell on Windows 7

Tags: windows, haskell

I'm aware of the following posts:

[Installing Haskell on Windows, cabal config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555250/installing-haskell-on-windows-cabal-config)

[How to modify cabal config file on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725607/how-to-modify-cabal-config-file-on-windows)

But they haven't been answered yet.

---

I have installed Haskell framework (GHCi) from [here](https://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html) on my Windows 7, but I'm still struggling with running simple files. For instance, I've saved this file in test.hs

```
data Car = Car Int deriving (Show)
```

Then I run :! ghc test.hs and then :! load test.hs. Both run without any error. But when I run:

```
Car 32
```

error like this appears:

```
data constructor not in scope: Car :: Integer -> t
```

I think I need to install more stuff but I don't know what.

I'm willing to use any other compilers, as long as they don't need any time consuming and complex configurations.

Comment: Please show the exact line that leads to that error.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks, I did.

Comment: What happens if you just paste this into a file and run it? https://repl.it/JKhB I seriously doubt this has anything to do with you needing to "install more stuff". Last time I used Haskell, I just installed the compiler package, and it worked.

Comment: @Carcigenicate    In this case, (after running !: ghc test.hs and :load test.hs) I need to type: main, then Car 32 would appear (successfully)! So, what's the problem?

Comment: I don't know, because `data constructor not in scope: Car :: Integer -> t` is a rather odd error. It leads me to believe you're missing some important information in the question.

Comment: Is that the entire contents of the file? I think you may need a `module` declaration first.

Comment: How is the module declared? I suspect that you must not be exporting the `Car` data constructor from your module.

Comment: What do you mean that you run `:! ghc test.hs` and `:! load test.hs`? From where? That doesn't look like valid Windows 7 commands.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I put : main= print () in the file as well as: data Car = Car Int deriving (Show).

Comment: @MarkSeemann I ran :! ghc test.hs and :! load test.hs in prelude.

Comment: What do you mean by "in prelude"? Are you running in GHCI?

Comment: @MarkSeemann Yes, I am. I think in the question I mentioned that I'm using GHCi.

Comment: Put `module Test (main, Car(Car)) where` at the top of your file.

Comment: What happens when you run `:! load test.hs`? `:!` means running an external program, in this case a program called `load`. There is, however, no `load` program on my Windows machine.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I've just tried:   :! load test.hs , it says: 'load' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: @4castle Yes, with module, thanks. I need to figure out how to change it when I have more data, e.g. Car, Bike, etc. But Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, there you go, then: your code isn't loaded.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thank you very much for the hints :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're on a command line with `ghcii.sh` in `PATH`, start by running it and loading your file:

```
$ ghcii.sh
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :load test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( 44872846.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> Car 32
Car 32
```

When you're alread in GHCi, you don't need to run `ghc` as an external command, since you're already in an interactive Haskell environment.

GHCi is only one of several programs included with GHC. It's a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), used for interactive, ad-hoc testing.

Another program included with GHC is `ghc.exe`. This is the compiler, which can turn your code into an `.exe` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but something important is missing in your answer which was @4castle comment: "Put   module Test (main, Car(Car))    where at the top of your file"

Comment: @4xx That would be an appropriate thing to do, but experimentation on my system shows that when you have the `main` function you wrote that you have, it's not _strictly_ necessary.